# Finding an implicit solution to $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac {y^2 + x \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}{xy} $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac {y^2 + x  \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}{xy} $$

This is the ODE I am trying to solve. My knowledge of solving DE's is rather limited. I have basically worked with exact equations, separable, linear and autonomous.

I am having trouble trying to see how I could use a substitution to turn this equation into one of them. I would be very grateful for any hints. Thank you !

Comment: homogeneous differential equation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac {x^2((\frac{y}{x})^2 +   \sqrt{1 + (\frac{y}{x})^2})}{x^2\frac{y}{x}}=\frac {(\frac{y}{x})^2 +   \sqrt{1 + (\frac{y}{x})^2}}{\frac{y}{x}} .$$ let $\frac{y}{x}=u\Rightarrow  \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{du}{dx}x+u$, so $$\frac{du}{dx}x+u=\frac {u^2 +   \sqrt{1 + u^2}}{u} \Rightarrow \frac{du}{dx}x=\frac {u^2 +   \sqrt{1 + u^2}}{u}-u=\frac {\sqrt{1 + u^2}}{u}$$so

$$\frac {u}{\sqrt{1 + u^2}}{du}=\frac{dx}{x}\Rightarrow \sqrt{1 + u^2}= \ln x+c$$
$\color{red}{\sqrt{1 + (\frac{y}{x})^2} = \ln x+c}$ is answer.

Comment: I believe that there is a displaced $x$ in the last equation. This then enables to subtract $u$ and simplify the right hand side...

Comment: @ewcz a mistake in type. I edit it.

Comment: I was a little confused until the edit. I would have never tried homogenous, thanks for showing me this solution !

Comment: you are welcome :)

Comment: quick question, don't you mean $\int\frac {u}{\sqrt{1 + u^2}}{du} = \sqrt{1+u^2}$

Comment: yes. you are right, my mistake